# After downloading to the hosting some parts of the layout stopped working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

Basically the whole question in the title. On local hosting, everything worked fine, but after loading, fragments html, for example switcher or checkbox, of the components of the Vue ceased to be displayed. I searched the whole day for information, I can not find anything, who faced help mee

Comment: Did you have a look in the developer console (F12) to 1) check the error causing the non-display and 2) the URL other parts of the application think they will find the missing pieces?

Comment: What is most interesting, the console is fine, and vue-devtools shows the correct data.

Comment: Tell us more about your setup. How did you deplay the frontend - build local + then upload? Or run the build on your server? Show your package.json. Have you tried running the build in productive environment (dev tools won't work anymore then)